# What does "frost your pickle" mean and where did it come from?

Tags: etymology, idioms

I hear my mom say this all time:

> Well doesn't that just frost your pickle?

I usually laugh because it sounds funny, but honestly I have no idea what it's really supposed to mean, in the sense that I don't really understand why "frost your pickle" makes sense as a phrase. She uses it to express a feeling of annoyance (I guess).

Can anyone identify the history/origin of this phrase? Why is the phrase used in this way?

Comment: Too localised, imho.

Comment: I don't think this is too localized: animuson's mom might be the only person who says this particular phrase, but like tchrist points out, there is a whole class of phrases of the same ilk, and the meaning of those can be used to suss out the meaning of this one. That said, @animuson, any chance you could ask your mom where she got this phrase from, and what she means when she says it?

Comment: Found a recipe for [frosted pickles](http://www.cooking.com/recipes-and-more/recipes/frosted-pickles-recipe-10000971.aspx#axzz1uWtKLbAH).

Comment: Does it appear like this idiom is used mostly/ only by women?

Comment: frost = make cold.  pickle = male genitalia.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found one use of the phrase on a Prince fan site's [discussion of the Beastie Boys](http://prince.org/msg/8/364998). This is from an 8/16/11 post from user Cerebus (quoted in full in honor of MCA):

> Been a diehard fan since License To Ill, which is like, 25 years ago. Been listening to the Beastie Boys almost as long as I've been listening to Prince. I love them. I love that they've changed over the years but are still clearly the Beastie Boys.
>
> However, while I can still get *way* into all the older stuff (especially Check Yo Head and Ill Communication), I find it much more difficult to really love the last two albums. I dug what To The 5 Burroughs was about and I enjoyed that they took the beats back to an early electro hip-hop sound, but I still don't think its a great album. The new album, for as long as it took to get it done (regardless of the health issues), didn't really **frost my pickle**. Its good, and I can feel the magic *trying* to creep in, but again, not great.
>
> I'll always be a fan and I'll always support them (including going to live shows if they ever tour again), but I think my real deep love for them probably ended with Hello Nasty.

So here it's being used in a positive way.

I found the *annoyance* sense of the phrase at a [Yahoo Answers question](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090129081522AAFRrVG) from a woman divorcing her husband and looking to sell his baseball card collection. This is the top-voted answer:

> well, hell, if's revenge you want why bother trying to sell them, give em away and tell him you did, that ought to **frost his pickle**!!

Could either of these posters be your mom?

**Edit**-- Keep finding more:

> -[One thing which **frosted my pickle** was no internet,and no
>   wireless.In 2011 this inexcusable](http://www.expedia.com/Maui-Island-Hotels-Kaanapali-Ocean-Inn.h1579462-p8.Hotel-Reviews)
>
> -[I kept getting hassled by guys who thought they were smoooooooooooooth… their primary means of greeting females being to smack them on the butt. This really just **frosted my pickle**.](http://justgerbil.wordpress.com/author/justgerbil/page/15/)
>
> -[I showed up for the meeting only to discover that it had been rescheduled. Now that really **frosted my pickle**!](http://lacubrious.blogspot.com/2005/07/late-night-wednesday.html)

I'd say the *annoyance* meaning wins out. Still no clue where it comes from, but it's definitely out there.

**Edit #2:**

After a little more looking around, I've found that the construction:

> Well, don't that just frost your [fill in the blank]!

is a fairly common US colloquialism used to express annoyance or, more specifically, sympathy for someone being annoyed or vexed. In addition to pickles, the various things being frosted in these expressions [include](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=to%20frost%20one%27s%20pickle&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%22if%20that%20don%27t%20just%20frost%22&hl=en&prmd=imvns&ei=0cG2T_7RIeKL2AXq_tCxCQ&sqi=2&start=10&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=19da35cdae5ee6d6&biw=1280&bih=705): *flakes* (after the cereal), *balls* (testicles), *knuckles*, *feathers*, *asses*, *hides*, and *cakes*.

I kept thinking this referred to *frost* as in *damaged by cold*, but this last one may hold a clue. These phrases could be a sarcastic reworking of the idiom

> [the frosting (icing) on the cake](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/icing?region=us&q=icing%20on%20the%20cake#icing__4)

by humorously emphasizing the unnecessary aspect of what has just happened. However, *NOAD* also has [this](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/frost?region=us&q=frost) informal definition of *frost*:

> anger or annoy
>
> *such discrimination frosted her no end*

So the question remains, is this informal use of *frost* a result of these colloquialisms or did *frost* carry this meaning before these colorful sayings were developed?